# MySql changing dates when selecting records

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2

I am using sequelize ORM with NodeJs. When i pass the value to DateTime column in where clause it automaticlly adds local offset.

For example i an writing this.

```
TripDetail.findOne({
   where: {
      trip_detail_id: trip_id,
      trip_detail_trip_start: '2017-10-05 15:27:38'
   },
})
```

The query it show is the log is

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_trip_detail` AS `TripDetail` 
WHERE `TripDetail`.`trip_detail_id` = 1
AND
`TripDetail`.`trip_detail_trip_start` = '2017-10-05 22:27:38'
```

My configuration for sequelize is

```
{
user: 'root',
password: '',
database: 'abc',
dialect: 'mysql',
options: {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  logging: console.log, // or specify sails log level to use ('info', 'warn', 'verbose', etc)
  dialectOptions: {
    timezone: 'utc', //for reading from database
    dateStrings: true,
    typeCast: function (field, next) { // for reading from database
      if (field.type === 'DATETIME') {
        return field.string()
      }
      return next()
    }
  },
},
```

}

i also tried removing dialectOptions Object completely.

Comment: Why are you treating dates as strings? Your `dialectOptions` asks `sequelize` to convert the date to UTC *and* pass it as a string. Why not use `Sequelize.DATE` in the model?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using Sequelize.Model, also dialectOptions not converting it to UTC, it returns date with offset.

Answer (score 0):

You should set right timezone in your configuration for sequelize 
like:

```
 timezone: '+08:00'
```

it depends which timezone you are

Comment: Where to add this? as timezone is already added in dialectOptions.